# Add calendar event from QR-encoded vcard

Tags: calendar, qr-code, vcard

Is there any way to BOTH

- decode QR codes for vcard-format calendar events without mangling the dates, AND
- add them to the calendar (ICS or newer) when recognized?

So far, using QR codes generated from two different sites (http://qrickit.com/qrickit_apps/qrickit_qrcode_creator_vcal.php and http://blog.qr4.nl/QR-Code-Calendar-Event.aspx), I've tried three apps. Two of them (QuickMark Lite and QR Barcode Scanner) misinterpreted the dates, and the one that got the dates right (AT&T Code Scanner) didn't know what to do with it after decoding (all it could do was decode it, and display it lamely in a text window).

Comment: Please note that according to our [FAQ] questions like "Is there an app for X" are off-topic. I re-phrased your question so it won't get closed due to that fact (guess you could live with a solution not involving any app if there were one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most barcode readers can recognize addresses. For calendar entries, this might vary; but give [QR Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=la.droid.qr) a try, which promises not only to read, but also create them: contacts, bookmarks, apps, geo-locations, events, and even SMS can be encoded as well as decoded. Also 2D barcodes (on products) should be supported.

Comment: Flawless solution. QR Droid worked perfectly & painlessly on the first try with the same QR codes that the two apps I tried yesterday choked on. :-)